# NOT IN with Remote Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having problems identifying whether a row exists in a local table from a remote server table or not. I have a job that inserts the result of a statement from a remote server (DB2) into a TABLE VARIABLE, and then I use NOT IN clause to identify what rows are new and insert those rows into a table.

This is not an efficient way to do this. Since when the transactions in the day start to grow the process become slow for obvious reasons I think. Here is an example of my code:

```
DECLARE @TRANS TABLE(Column1 INT,
Column2 NVARCHAR(20),
Column3 NVARCHAR(20),
Column4 NVARCHAR(20),
Column5 NVARCHAR(20),
Column6 NVARCHAR(20),
Column7 NVARCHAR(20));


INSERT INTO @TRANS
EXEC ('SELECT 
Column1,
Column2,
Column3,
Column4,
Column5,
Column6,
Column7

FROM SCHEMA.RemoteTable 
WHERE Date = '+@DATE) AT [DB2RemoteServer]


INSERT INTO TransactionTable
SELECT * FROM
@TRANS TRANS 
WHERE TRANS.Column1 NOT IN (SELECT Column1 FROM TransactionTable  WHERE
Column1 = TRANS.Column1 AND Some other conditions...)
```

Right now it's working, but not in the most efficient way.

NOTE: I can't modify data from the remote server to mark the transactions already inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. NOT EXISTS.

```
INSERT INTO TransactionTable
SELECT * FROM
@TRANS TRANS 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TransactionTable  WHERE
Column1 = TRANS.Column1 AND Some other conditions...)
```